# Squished Text On Website

Tags: css, webfonts, google-webfonts

I am using a google web font on a site and am getting some users reporting very squished unreadable text throughout the entire site. I am unable to see this any browser or computer I use, so I am not sure what could be causing this.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Any suggestions to fix this would be great. Thanks!

Here is the url to site: http://odditymall.com

Comment: Well from this image it looks like your font is squished. Depending on the size of the font, maybe that is what they are talking about. But unless there is a fiddle or direct site to look at it, not sure if we can help you.

Comment: Please show us what kind of font you are using as well as any CSS styles applied to your text.  You can look at this in your browsers debugger by inspecting the element with the text on it.

Comment: Thanks, see the new edit for the url.

Comment: Do your user reports include their browser?  Are you testing in all browsers?

Comment: I have just had 2 users report this, one was on chrome, the other on IE, this screenshot was from the user on chrome. I did/do test on all major browsers.

Comment: Looks mighty fine on my side, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Can you post part of the screenshot showing more details? It looks like the font used has been changed to some odd font, but more details would be needed for an analysis. Can you check whether the two users have the same problem with the *current* version of the page? The current page Do those users have something special in common?

Comment: Oh, and where is the code that uses Google Web Fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having the same issue... From google fonts, I was getting the 'Droid Serif' font, but in my css I was using:

```
font-family: 'Droid', arial, verdana;
```

So, since droid did not exist anywhere, the text on the site would look like the screenshot above for a very small amount of people (for whatever reason). To fix it for those people, I just had to change it to:

```
font-family: 'Droid Serif', arial, verdana;
```

Answer (score 0):

i would guess your website is not responsive and u have done some html/css changes to your website so its causing it like that. y dont u try accessing the source through chrome element inspector and then play with the code maybe u'll find ur answer there. else send the site link so we could check it up, if thats possible though..

Comment: Not an answer to the question.